# Read parquet files created in last 2 hours in Pypark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-active-directory, parquet, azure-blob-storage

I want to read multiple parquet files in Azure Blob Storage created in the last 2 hours.

I can read multiple files with the below command

```
df = sqlContext.read.parquet("/path/*.parquet")
```

This query is returning the result from all the parquet files present in that folder, now I want to get the data only from the parquet files created in the last 2 hours.

Please help me in getting the command right.

Answer (score 3):

One way is using [Hadoop FS API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) [`listStatus`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listStatus-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-) method to list all the files under that folder, select those that were modified in the last two hours using `getModificationTime` and pass the filtered list of files to Spark DataFrame reader.

In Pyspark you can access hadoop fs through the JVM gateway like this :

```py
import datetime


Path = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
conf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()

data_path = "/path/*.parquet"

fs = Path(data_path).getFileSystem(conf)
file_status = fs.listStatus(Path(data_path))

last_2hours_time = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=2)).timestamp() * 1000

created_last_2hours = [
  f.getPath().toString() for f in file_status if f.getModificationTime() >= last_2hours_time
]

df = spark.read.parquet(*created_last_2hours)
```

You may also want to take a look at [Python package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python) for Azure Blob Storage to list the files.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. this code worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of addressing is to use spark [Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) with checkpointing.

Run it first over the entire data & then with the same checkpoint run your specific business logic every 2 hours:

- The first run will populate the checkpoint data, so that you won't go over the same files during the second run.
- You can make the first run with empty logic, such as doing nothing in the `my_function()` example below.

```py
spark.readStream.parquet("/path/*.parquet")\
    .writeStream \
    .trigger(once=True) \
    .outputMode('append') \
    .format("delta") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path) \
    .start(path) \
    .awaitTermination()
```

OR something like

```py
def my_function(df, epochId): 
    # do anything here


spark.readStream.parquet("/path/*.parquet") \
    .writeStream \
    .trigger(once=True) \
    .foreachBatch(my_function) \
    .option('checkpointLocation', 'some_location') \
    .start() \
    .awaitTermination()
```

See other [examples](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/examples.html#foreach-dynamodb-example)